# How to remove underline in TextInput (Expo - react native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an underline issue in android where, as I type, the letters get underlined as shown. This doesn't happen in ios. I tried below properties but nothing worked.

```
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
autoCorrect='false'
```

`underlineColorAndroid` - If this is set to some other color then I have a double underline (in below example I've set to green and then transparent).

[image]

Here I get green as well as white underline. white underline is only under the letter I type and **I want to get rid of this white underline**.

[image]

[image]

Reference : https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it correctly like:

```
<TextInput
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    />
```

and still not working like in my case, i just did a work around it.

since changing its color is working, how about this:

```
underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' // make the numbers match the backround color.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but No, that doesn't work unfortunately. By doing this, we can hide one of the long lines but not the white line under the letters